# 'IterableSimpleNamespace' object has no attribute 'parent'

Tags: object-detection, real-time, yolov8

I am trying to use yolov8 for real-time webcam-fed video object detection.

So, in my track.py file I have this block of code:

```
@hydra.main(version_base=None, config_path=str(DEFAULT_CFG.parent), config_name=DEFAULT_CFG.name)
def predict(cfg):
    init_tracker()
    random_color_list()

    cfg.model = cfg.model or "yolov8n.pt"
    cfg.imgsz = check_imgsz(cfg.imgsz, min_dim=2)
    cfg.source = cfg.source if cfg.source is not None else ROOT / "assets"
    

    predictor = DetectionPredictor(cfg)

    predictor()
```

And, when I try to run the `track.py` file with the following line of code,

`C:\yolov8\ultralytics\ultralytics\models\yolo\detect> yolo predict model=yolov8l.pt source=0 imgsz=640 show=True`

It throws the following error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\yolov8\ultralytics\ultralytics\models\yolo\detect\track.py", line 177, in <module>
    @hydra.main(version_base=None, config_path=str(DEFAULT_CFG.parent), config_name=DEFAULT_CFG.name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\utils\__init__.py", line 172, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(f"""
AttributeError:
            'IterableSimpleNamespace' object has no attribute 'parent'. This may be caused by a modified or out of date ultralytics
            'default.yaml' file.
Please update your code with 'pip install -U ultralytics' and if necessary replace
            C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\cfg\default.yaml with the latest version from
            https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/blob/main/ultralytics/cfg/default.yaml
```

I have tried installing the ultralytics, and also replaced the default.yaml file from the ultralytics github repository.

But when I use `yolo predict model=yolov8n.pt source=0 imgsz=640 show=True` in any location, it works fine. I am also confused about how it is working with this command.

Can you please help me??

P.S.: I followed the video [YOLOv8 Object Tracking in Real-time with Webcam and OpenCV](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UYLp0-iOvFc) to create this project.